# SQL statement won't run without "`" around the field names

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am running an application and on one of my sql tables, it will not run queries unless the "`" character is around the field names and i have no idea why this is required??

for instance

```
INSERT INTO doc_elements (doc_pdf_id, element_type, class, id, order, create_timestamp) VALUES ('37', 'p', 'ft2', '0', '3', '1337130927')
```

will not work, but this will work:

```
INSERT INTO `doc_elements`(`doc_pdf_id`, `element_type`, `class`, `id`, `order`, `create_timestamp`) VALUES ('37', 'p', 'ft2', '0', '3', '1337130927')
```

It is the only table in the database that requires the "`" be wrapped around the field names in order to give a correct sql statement.

I can run this perfectly fine in another table:

```
INSERT INTO doc_pdfs (act_id, upload_stamp) VALUES ('xxxxx12234', '1337130927')
```

table structure for the table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `doc_elements` (
`doc_elements_id` int(15) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`doc_pdf_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`element_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`class` varchar(100) default NULL,
`id` varchar(100) default NULL,
`order` int(11) NOT NULL,
`parent_element` int(15) default NULL,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
`create_timestamp` int(20) NOT NULL,
`sys_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY  (`doc_elements_id`),
KEY `doc_pdf_id` (`doc_pdf_id`),
KEY `parent_element` (`parent_element`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: what is the error? what is the rdbms? could be you are using a keyword as a column name. could be you created a case sensitive id by using quotes at creation time and need to use the quotes again if you want to query lowercase (Oracle)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ORDER` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

Comment: ORDER is a reserved word in all dialects of SQL.

Comment: yep that now works. thanks for that. i knew it was going to be something simple :)